# How to truncate a date to the first day of the month in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-arithmetic

I am not able to find any good conversion code to get `2014-02-17 into 2014-02-01` without having to use concatenation and a ton of formatting.
I wonder if someone can help me find a good command to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another option:

SELECT TRUNCTIMESTAMPTOMONTH(CURRENT_DATE());

Answer (score 15):

Snowflake supports [`date_trunc()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) for datatypes `DATE`, `TIME`, and `TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(month, CURRENT_DATE()) AS first_day_of_month;
```

Comment: GMB's answer is the most appropiate one, I am also sharing the entire SQL that you can use select date_trunc('MONTH', to_date('2014-02-17')) as FIRST_DAY_MONTH;

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're working with strings.   If that's the case and they'll always be in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd', you can just take the first 8 characters and add '01':

```sql
left(MyStringValue, 8) + '01'
```

If you're working with date fields, I like the trick of doing `datediff` to get the months from 0, then use `dateadd` with 0 to get back to the first of the month:

```sql
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, MyDateValue), 0)
```